# Exclude specific GeoJSON data by polygon

Tags: polygon, javascript, geojson, software-recommendations, filter

Given geospatial data as GeoJSON, how can I filter this data to exclude geometries within a specified polygon?

I need this to work in JavaScript. Example:

```
function filter(featureCollection, filterPolygon) {
    return //geometries in featureCollection not within filterPolygon
}
```

Comment: There are likely dozens of such libraries. Please [Edit] your question to specify the language, though you might be better off asking such a subjective question in [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: It needs to be a JavaScript Lib

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at turf.js (http://turfjs.org/). Combine with a js filter on the features array